# Bad enum values in AWS Aurora

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

How do I set server configuration variables in Aurora?  I want to set strict mode (innodb_strict_mode in mysql variables) on so I don't get bad values in enum columns.

Comment: Go to the RDS dashboard, select Parameter Groups.  Create a new parameter group and attach that to your RDS instance.  Edit the parameter group to include sql_mode STRICT_ALL_TABLES.  Save the parameters and reboot the server.